# No sound on Ubuntu 18.4 on mini PC connected to TV via HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi

First time installing any Linux a few days ago and I have limited experience using Ubuntu.

Mini PC is Cherry Trail core, with Intel Atom x5-Z8350  CPU @ 1.44GHz, and is connected via HDMI to Sony TV in port 1.

Having checked a lot of posts I've done a lot in alsamixer and pavuconrol.  In alsamixer the soundcards are listed as bytcr-rt5651 and Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio.  The default is bytcr-rt5651 and it has loads of options to adjust, but the HDMI one which I presume I should use only has one volume bar labelled PCM which is set to 100.  I set it to this card but it always opens on the other when I reopen it.

In pavucontrol it usually just says establishing connection, but when it does open I have set my processor's profile to Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output under configuration, and its port to HDMI/DisplayPort.

There are also options in pavucontrol for Built-in Audio Speaker playback but I assume this is not relevant to me?  I have its profile set to off.

In sound settings, it used to list no output devices, but reading similar posts has helped me get three listed now,

- HDMI / DisplayPort - Atom.....Configuration Registers
- Analogue Output - Atom....Configuration Registers
- Speaker playback - Built-in Audio.

I've selected HDMI but the test speakers options give no sound on any of them.

There is also nothing listed under Applications and it says no application is playing or recording audio even when I have YouTube or the video player running.

Lastly video playback, be it from the video player or in browser, sometimes runs far too fast.  This is only relevant to this question as I have noticed this issue come and go as I've adjusted audio settings,so it appears related.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit**:

I installed VLC player and it plays video and gives error message:

> Audio output failed.
>   Audio device "default" could not be used.
>   No such file or directory.

When I look to try another audio device "default" is the only option.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working thanks to advice on Reddit r/linux4noobs so posting here in case anyone else with the same problem ends up reading this.

The solution was to abandon 18.04 LTS and install 18.10. Worked from install.